# Code in Application_Activated not running when phone wakes up

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I've done some reseach on the life cycle of Windows Phone apps and I've gathered that when the phone is locked whilst an app is still running, and you unlock the phone the 'Application_Activated' function is called in the App.xaml.cs file.

```
// Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
// This code will not execute when the application is first launched
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    //Code to run
    MessageBox.Show("Hello there!");
}
```

Now in the above example, the simple 'MessageBox' call doesn't get run. Like I said, if you have your app running and you lock the phone, and then unlock the phone the above code is expected to run, in this case display a MessageBox as soon as you unlock the phone.

Any help would really be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that

```
If you call Show(String) method from the app Activated and Launching event 
handlers an InvalidOperationException is thrown with the message Error 
Displaying MessageBox.
```

[it is in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

if you wanna show same message my suggestion is to use `OnNavigatedTo` event

**EDIT**

if i understood correctly you wanna change default page navigation

1. 1.One way to do this:

   In `WMAppManifest.xml` replace the property of `Navigation Page` with  your desire page
2. An alternative:

In `WMAppManifest.xml` remove the property of `Navigation Page`

> ```
> private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
> {
>     RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("YourPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); 
> }
> ```

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{            
     RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("YourPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

This way you can "play" with `IsolatedStorageSettings` for example

```
     if (boolvariable)
        {
            RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("YourPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            boolvariable = false;
        }
     else 
        {
            RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

It just an idea, let me know how it goes (:

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out. The MessageBox.Show() was really only a way to test it. What I'm actually wanting to do is navigate to a .xaml page that I already have created.

I.e. when you lock the phone and unlock it, the app will automatically navigate to 'main_screen.xaml' for instance. Regardless of what page you were on when you locked the screen. How would I get that to work?

Comment: please take a look of my answer now