# How To Navigate our own page in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation

I am a new one for windows phone development.

I am working one windows phone project.In this project default or when app launching load the MainPage.xaml. But I want load my own page at the time of launching app with check some condition.

Example i create one variable i in App.xaml, that i value is equal to 1 then go to odd.xaml otherwise it's go to even.xaml.

I am trying some code. It doesn't work.

And i some link. But I can't understand the logic.

Please give the brief explanation with example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay first off, congradulations on deving for windows phone. It's a great device. If you want to post here however you need to post code examples. Your speaking broken english and gave a confusing problem. In order to get any type of answer you need to post something we can all (hopfully) understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change startup page on WP7 application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247908/how-to-change-startup-page-on-wp7-application)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758511/code-in-application-activated-not-running-when-phone-wakes-up/15759618#15759618